# Simple OpenGL / C++ Game Engine

Tags: c++, opengl

I come from a C# background and recently have been trying to improve my C++ and OpenGL. I've hacked together a basic 3d engine and am looking for feedback as to how to improve it.

One bit I'm most unsure about is the render loop for multiple objects, I've set it up like this and would love some feedback on it. For instance I've no idea if my use of pointers is optimal.

scene.hpp:

```
namespace r3d
{
    class scene
    {
        public:
            scene(int width, int height);
            void update();
            void exit();
            void add_object(r3d::game_object *);
            void add_light(r3d::light *);
            GLFWwindow * window;
            r3d::camera * main_camera;
    };
}
```

This is the main loop in my scene.cpp file:

```
void scene::update()
{
    time->update();

    // render scene loop
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    behaviour * script;

    for(auto it = game_objects.begin(); it != game_objects.end(); ++it)
    {
        if(!(*it)->enabled) { continue; }

        script = (behaviour *)(*it)->get_component(constants::BEHAVIOUR);
        if(script)
        {
            script->update();
        }
    }

    mesh_renderer * render_obj;

    for(auto it = game_objects.begin(); it != game_objects.end(); ++it)
    {
        if(!(*it)->enabled) { continue; }

        render_obj = (mesh_renderer *)(*it)->get_component(constants::RENDER_OBJECT);

        // use our shader
        render_obj->material->shader->bind();

        // set camera uniforms
        main_camera->set_uniforms(render_obj->material->shader, (*it)->get_transform());

        // set light uniforms
        lights.front()->set_uniforms(render_obj->material->shader);

        // bind texture
        render_obj->material->bind();

        // bind buffers and draw elements
        render_obj->render();
    }

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
}
```

shader.hpp:

```
namespace r3d
{
    class shader
    {
        public:
            enum id { UNLIT_VERT_COLOR, UNLIT_TEXTURE, DIFFUSE };
            shader(id);
            shader(std::string, std::string);
            void bind();
            id shader_id;
            GLuint program;
            GLuint mvp_matrix;
            GLuint view_matrix;
            GLuint model_matrix;
            GLuint texture_sampler;
            GLuint light_world_pos;
            GLuint light_color;
            GLuint light_intensity;

        private:
            void init(std::string, std::string);
    };
}
```

shader.cpp:

```
shader::shader(std::string vert, std::string frag)
{
    init(vert, frag);
}

void shader::init(std::string vert, std::string frag)
{
    program = load_shader(vert.c_str(), frag.c_str());

    // Get handles for our uniforms
    mvp_matrix = glGetUniformLocation(program, "MVP");
    view_matrix = glGetUniformLocation(program, "V");
    model_matrix = glGetUniformLocation(program, "M");
    texture_sampler = glGetUniformLocation(program, "Sampler");
    light_world_pos = glGetUniformLocation(program, "LightPosition_worldspace");
    light_color = glGetUniformLocation(program, "LightColor");
    light_intensity = glGetUniformLocation(program, "LightPower");

    glUseProgram(program);
}

void shader::bind()
{
    glUseProgram(program);
}
```

camera.hpp:

```
namespace r3d
{
    class camera : public game_object
    {
        public:
            camera();
            camera(int w, int h) : width(w), height(h) {};
            void set_uniforms(r3d::shader *, glm::mat4);
            float fov = 45;
            float near = 0.1f;
            float far = 100.0f;
            int width = 1024;
            int height = 768;

        private:
            glm::mat4 projection;
            glm::mat4 view;
    };
}
```

camera.cpp:

```
using namespace r3d;

void camera::set_uniforms(r3d::shader * shader, glm::mat4 model)
{
    view = glm::lookAt(position, position + forward, up);

    projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(fov), (float)width / (float)height, near, far);

    glm::mat4 mvp = projection * view * model;

    glUniformMatrix4fv(shader->mvp_matrix, 1, GL_FALSE, &mvp[0][0]);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(shader->model_matrix, 1, GL_FALSE, &model[0][0]);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(shader->view_matrix, 1, GL_FALSE, &view[0][0]);
}
```

light.hpp:

```
namespace r3d
{
    class light
    {
        public:
            light();
            light(glm::vec3, glm::vec3, float);
            void set_uniforms(r3d::shader *);

            glm::vec3 position;
            glm::vec3 color;
            float intensity;
    };
}
```

light.cpp:

```
light::light(glm::vec3 position, glm::vec3 color, float intensity)
{
    this->position = position;
    this->color = color;
    this->intensity = intensity;
}

void light::set_uniforms(r3d::shader * shader)
{
    glUniform3f(shader->light_world_pos, position.x, position.y, position.z);
    glUniform3f(shader->light_color, color.x, color.y, color.z);
    glUniform1f(shader->light_intensity, intensity);
}
```

mesh_renderer.hpp:

```
namespace r3d
{
    class mesh_renderer : public component
    {
        public:
            mesh_renderer();
            mesh_renderer(std::string, r3d::material *);
            void render();

            std::vector<unsigned short> indices;
            std::vector<glm::vec3> vertices;
            std::vector<glm::vec2> uvs;
            std::vector<glm::vec3> normals;
            GLuint vertex_array_object;
            GLuint vertex_buffer;
            GLuint uv_buffer;
            GLuint normal_buffer;
            GLuint indices_buffer;
            r3d::material * material;
    };
}
```

mesh_renderer.cpp:

```
using namespace r3d;

mesh_renderer::mesh_renderer(std::string model_path, r3d::material * material)
{
    name = "mesh_renderer";

    this->material = material;

    // Read file
    load_mesh(model_path.c_str(), indices, vertices, uvs, normals);

    // Vertex Array Object
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertex_array_object);
    glBindVertexArray(vertex_array_object);

    // Vertex buffer
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertex_buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3), &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // UV buffer
    glGenBuffers(1, &uv_buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uv_buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uvs.size() * sizeof(glm::vec2), &uvs[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Normal buffer
    glGenBuffers(1, &normal_buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normal_buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normals.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3), &normals[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Indices buffer
    glGenBuffers(1, &indices_buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices_buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.size() * sizeof(unsigned short), &indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Remove bindings
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    printf("Add mesh_renderer: %s [indices: %lu]\n", model_path.c_str(), indices.size());
}

void mesh_renderer::render()
{
    // vao
    glBindVertexArray(vertex_array_object);

    // vertex buffer
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);

    // uv buffer
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uv_buffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);

    // normal buffer
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normal_buffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);

    // index buffer
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices_buffer);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (void*)0);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

Full source code is here if anyone wants to look at/review any further:

https://github.com/ryanw3bb/r3d

Any feedback or comments would be hugely appreciated! :)

Comment: It would be really helpful for reviewers if you included the relevant header files, too. As it stands now, we can only guess the types of member variables, which hinders any meaningful analysis.

Comment: Cheers, headers added

Comment: [This post is being discussed on meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8880/clarification-on-close-reason?cb=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class scene
{
    public:
        scene(int width, int height);
        void update();
        void exit();
        void add_object(r3d::game_object *);
        void add_light(r3d::light *);
        GLFWwindow * window;
        r3d::camera * main_camera;
};
```

It’s odd to indent more levels for the `public`.  I mention this because at first glance I thought it was nested namespaces.

You have members that are raw pointers, but have not declared any destructor, copy constructor, assignment operator.  What happens if you write

```
scene x {2,3};
scene y = x;
```

?

Look up “Rule of zero/three/five”.  Always consider the value semantics of your classes.  This is something different from what you are used to in C#!

---

The style in C++ is to put the `*` or `&` with the *type*, not the identifier.  This is called out specifically near the beginning of Stroustrup’s first book, and is an intentional difference from C style.

---

```
for(auto it = game_objects.begin(); it != game_objects.end(); ++it)
{
    if(!(*it)->enabled) { continue; }

    script = (behaviour *)(*it)->get_component(constants::BEHAVIOUR);
    if(script)
    {
        script->update();
    }
}
```

First, use the range-`for` loop.  This *should* be familiar to you from C# :

```
for (auto item : game_objects) {
```

Now I can’t tell if you really want to copy the items or not, so you might mean `const auto&` there instead?

Don’t define your variables until you are ready to initialize them.
Then, use the define/test idiom so that the variable `script` is only in scope to use *where it is valid*!

```
    if (auto script = get_behavior(item)) {
        script->update();
    }
```

Notice how I avoided the ghastly furball you had in the original by making a named function to hide that *and* make sure the cast and parameter are matched, **in one place** in the code.

For that, you *should* use component storage that doesn’t require casting!  Why can’t you simply have named (typed!) members in the game_object?  If you must decouple knowledge of your types here from the game_object code, look into strongly typed ways of doing that.  E.g. store a `std::any`, use a system like the localle objects in the standard library (though that is rather dated), … I could offer more specific advice if I knew the details.

Where you do cast, never use C-style casts.

```
auto get_behavior (game_object_t& item)
{
    return static_cast<behavior*>(item->get_component(constants::BEHAVIOR);
}
```

I don’t know if you need static or reinterpret cast, but assuming you are storing a base class in the collection, you are downcasting to take it out.  You *really* should use `dynamic_cast`, but that is slow.  I suggest though using conditional compilation to turn on `dynamic_cast` when you are debugging, to validate what you think is happening.

---

```
        shader(std::string, std::string);
        void init(std::string, std::string);
```

I wonder why you are taking strings by value.  Given your C# background, perhaps by mistake?

The one-line body should be in the header in-line in the class.  But as written, `init` is *really* the constructor, so move the contents to the constructor and initialize the members rather than default initializing and then assigning over them.

I see that you don’t need a copy of the string at all, and would actually prefer not creating a string to pass at all if you have a plain literal.  So I’ll change that to `string_view`.

```
  shader::shader (string_view vert, string_view frag)
   : program{ load_shader(vert.c_str(),frag.c_str()) },  // N.B. must be initialized first! ※
     mvp_matrix{ glGetUniformLocation(program,"MVP") },
       ⋮
   {
       glUseProgram(program);
   }
```

I don’t see any definition of `shader::shader(id)` but I suppose it would share most of the same code, right?  Use a delegating constructor to have one call the other or both call a private form.

**※** Members are initialized in the order in which they are declared in the class, *not* the order presented in the constructor’s init list.

---

Good luck to you!

Moving to C++, I suggest you learn about value semantics.  Constructors, assignment, etc.; both how they are used by the code and how you write them.  You will find important differences from things called constructors in C# and Java (and Delphi for that matter).

Links for you:

- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three
- https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md

Answer (score 3):

This looks really interesting! If you end up using it for a game, let us know so we can try it out!

## Namespaces

You've chosen the namespace `r3d`. Just be aware that the Red Camera company uses `r3d` as their file extension and they have [an SDK](https://www.red.com/developers) for reading in files from their format. Not sure if they use C++ namespaces, but thought you should know.

## Architecture

I notice in `scene`, you have loops where you're doing:

```
for (auto it = game_objects.begin(); it != game_objects.end(); ++it)
{
    if (!(*it)->enabled) { continue; }
    //... etc.
}
```

I'm guessing you use this elsewhere, too. If this is a common task in your engine, it would probably be worth having different types of iterators, such as an "enabled objects" iterator. You're also casting the results to specific types, so it might even be worthwhile to have "enabled behaviors" iterators and "enabled mesh renderer" iterators. Or that might be overkill. It all depends on how you're going to use them and how frequently you need to differentiate them.

Some of your architecture feels inside-out to me. For example, you have a `set_uniforms()` method on `camera` and `light`. Neither cameras nor lights have uniforms (in your classes, in OpenGL, or logically). Shaders have uniforms. So you should be calling `render_obj->material->shader->set_uniforms()`. (Or perhaps it would be better to have a `set_lighting_uniforms()` method and a `set_camera_uniforms()` method.)

I'm also unclear on why some things are left to the `scene::update()` method and some are in `mesh_renderer::render()`. For example, you call `shader::bind()` from `scene::update()`, but directly call `glBindVertexArray()`, and `glBindBuffer()` in `mesh_renderer::render()`. I would think the `render` method should set up the fragment and vertex shaders, set their uniforms, set up the various arrays and buffers and call `glDrawElements()`.

## Avoid Magic Numbers

You use `glGetUniformLocation()` to get the locations of each uniform in `shader::init()`. But you're using hard-coded constants for the vertex attributes. You could use [`glGetAttributeLocation()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetAttribLocation.xhtml) to get the locations of your attributes. Then they would have names in your C++ code and be more readable. It would make it easier to spot errors if, for example, you accidentally sent vertices to your normal buffer or vice-versa. Or, if you don't want to do that, at least use named constants instead of hardcoding 0, 1, and 2 to mean vertices, texture coordinates, and normals.

Likewise, when passing in the number of coordinates for each attribute, I would use the type names, like this:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(vertex_attribute, sizeof(glm::vec3) / sizeof(GLfloat), GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);
```

or better:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(vertex_attribute, sizeof(vertices[0]) / sizeof(vertices[0].x), GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);
```

This ensures the number of coordinates per element is always correct without hardcoding the value.

## Member Access

You've made almost all of your instance variables `public`. This is generally a bad idea. It means that any code at all can just reach in and change those values. It makes debugging much harder as when you do find an object with a bad value, it becomes impossible to track down where it was set. Most of your instance variables should probably be `private`. It looks like many of your instance variables are only used within the class in which they're declared, so it probably wouldn't cause much disruption to do this.

## Odds and Ends

Your `camera` class has a `width` and `height`. This is odd as a virtual camera has no inherent width and height. It does have an aspect ratio, though, and I see that's all you use `width` and `height` for. I would have the constructor just save the ratio rather than separately saving the width and height. This would also avoid the cast in `camera::set_uniforms()`. (That is, it would move it to the constructor.)

I would also probably store the field of view in radians so it's not converted on every frame. (Not that it's likely to be a performance bottleneck. Just why save the data in a different format than the one you actually need?)

You appear to only be supporting point lights. Directional and spot lights are not too difficult to implement and will give you additional creative options.

Comment: ⟪it would probably be worth having different types of iterators, such as an "enabled objects" iterator.⟫  Indeed!  Better yet, make a set of composable [*range adaptors*](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/introduction.html) that can be attached to any collection of game items in a range-`for` loop. E.g. `for(auto& item : game_objects | enabled) { ⋯`